# (Index, value) Pairs while looping through an Array

Tags: arrays, swift

In Swift 2.0, the following code worked:

```
import UIKit

var arr = [5, 77, 34, -22]

for (index, value) in enumerate(arr) {

    // arr[index] = value + 1      This works, but the line below is more relevant for the following code.

    arr[index] = arr[index] + 1

}

println(arr)
```

To give:

```
[6, 78, 35, -21]
```

I tried the same in Swift 3.0 with the following code:

```
import UIKit

var arr = [5, 77, 34, -22]

var y = arr.count

for x in 0...y {

    arr[x] = arr[x] + 1

}

print(arr)
```

But, I got an error for the only line inside the for-loop saying "error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION". Any ideas on what went wrong or what syntax I could use to get the (index, value) pair as in the first program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `let`, since you're not declaring any new variables.

Better yet, just use `map`:

```
let numbers = [5, 77, 34, -22]
let incremented = numbers.map{ $0 + 1 }
```

Comment: removing let did not fix the issue. I got an error saying "error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION". Will update my post with this information.

Comment: @StopReadingThisUsername Look carefully at the indices you're looping over

Comment: @StopReadingThisUsername That's why you should never manually use `for i in 0...arr.count`, in favour of `for i in arr.indicies`. It prevents you from being susceptible to making this simple error

Comment: For some reason, replacing arr.count with arr.indices and y - 1 with y did not work. It gave me an error saying "Binary operator '...' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'CountableRange<Array.Index>'"

Comment: @StopReadingThisUsername What exactly did you write?

Comment: var arr = [5, 77, 34, -22]; 

var y = arr.indices; 

    for x in 0...y {
    
        arr[x] = arr[x] + 1
    
    };

Sorry about the formatting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144798/discussion-between-alexander-and-stopreadingthisusername).